# using joins in sql - not getting all wanted results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to query my mysql DB with the following sql :

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
    t1.Discipline,
    t4disc.Color,
    t4disc.Naam,
    t1.Date_Posted,
    t2ploeg.Naam PloegId,
    t1.Cat,
    t1.Tekst,
    t3user.Naam PosterId,
    t3user.Voornaam
    FROM Log_Logboek_".$log." t1
    JOIN Log_Ploegen_".$log." t2ploeg ON t1.PloegId = t2ploeg.ID
    JOIN Log_Users t3user ON t1.PosterId = t3user.ID
    JOIN Log_Disciplines t4disc ON t1.Discipline = t4disc.ID
    ". $where ."
    AND t1.Discipline in ($vis_ids)
    ORDER by Date_Posted asc;
     ";
```

This query does work and gives results. The only problem with the joins is that if one of the joined tables doesn't contain a matching Id, the row gets skipped from the results entirely.
Let's say, for example, a user is deleted from the Log_Users table, than all records with his ID gets skipped in this query because there is no matching user for the t1.PosterId.

Is there a way of joining these tables so I can do it in one query, and still getting all row in the results ? If so, can i substitute the missing id's in someway ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace your `join`s with `left join`.  That is the SQL construct that does what you want.

Comment: This is idd the way to get all results with 'null's filling the unknown id's. The problem with this is that now my where-statement isn't working any more : `$where = ' AND t1.Date_Posted >= '.$timestamp;`Any idea's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT t1.Discipline, t4disc.Color, t4disc.Naam, t1.Date_Posted, t2ploeg.Naam PloegId,
       t1.Cat, t1.Tekst, t3user.Naam PosterId, t3user.Voornaam
FROM Log_Logboek_".$log." t1 LEFT JOIN
     Log_Ploegen_".$log." t2ploeg
     ON t1.PloegId = t2ploeg.ID LEFT JOIN
     Log_Users t3user
     ON t1.PosterId = t3user.ID LEFT JOIN
     Log_Disciplines t4disc
     ON t1.Discipline = t4disc.ID
". $where ."t1.Discipline in ($vis_ids)
ORDER by Date_Posted asc;
```

The condition in the `where` clause is on the first table, so it will filter the rows accordingly.  If there are no matches to the condition, then all might be filtered out.

If you move the `where` conditions to the `on` clause, then a strange thing happens with left outer joins.  The `on` condition fails, but the row is still kept in the result set -- that is how left outer joins work.

Comment: Got it ! the $where I was using started with `AND ...` which worked in my previous sql with the normal Joins. With the left joins, I replaced the `AND` with `WHERE` and then it worked ! Thx for the help!